# Can't make my Phoenix app build on Heroku CI

Tags: heroku, elixir, phoenix-framework, heroku-ci

I can't manage to make my Phoenix 1.2 app to run on Heroku CI.

It seems it's trying to create a new database, and even though I configured an alias, it's still performing `ecto.create`.

Here is Heroku CI output:

```
-----> Running Elixir buildpack tests... 10:25:25.751 [warn] Warning: No valid AppSignal configuration found, continuing with AppSignal metrics disabled. 10:25:26.071 [error] GenServer #PID<0.903.0> terminating
** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL (insufficient_privilege): permission denied for database "template1" User does not have CONNECT privilege.
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:148: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3 Last message: nil
** (Mix) The database for PhenixDisplays.Repo couldn't be created: FATAL (insufficient_privilege): permission denied for database "template1" User does not have CONNECT privilege.
-----> Elixir buildpack tests failed with exit status 1
```

My `mix.exs` aliases function

```
  defp aliases do
    [
      "ecto.setup": ["ecto.create", "ecto.migrate", "run priv/repo/seeds.exs"],
      "ecto.reset": ["ecto.drop", "ecto.setup"],
      "test": ["ecto.migrate", "test"]
    ]
  end
```

And my repo setup in `test.exs`

```
config :phenix_displays, PhenixDisplays.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  url: System.get_env("DATABASE_URL") || "postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/phenix_displays_test",
  pool: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox,
  extensions: [{Geo.PostGIS.Extension, library: Geo}, {PhenixDisplays.Postgrex.Box2D, []}]
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that `mix ecto.setup` is being called as part of the preparations to run your tests. HerokuCI seems to use an `app.json` file for configuration of your tests. This is an example I found at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-ci

```
{
  "environments": {
    "test": {
      "scripts": {
        "test-setup": "gem install rubocop",
        "test": "rubocop ."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure that the correct `test-setup` is configured and that it only runs the commands you want it to run.